# Using filters in swift for checklist part in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, filter

We are working on an iOS application where we have recipes. In the first page of the app, we have list of ingredients. The user chooses the ingredients and the app is supposed to list the recipes that you can make with the ingredients chosen. We thought filters would be a good idea and we did this. Do you think there is a way we can improve the following code or what can we do for this scenario.

Also this code is giving error at the last line.

```
    let array = [
            ["id":"Simple and healty salmon", "Ingr": "Salmon"],//in Simple and healty salmon,there is salmon only as ingridient.When salmon is checked ,Simple and healthy salmon recipe has to come out.
            ["id":"Boiled Eggs", "Ingr": "Egg"],//other recipies are as follows
            ["id":"Perfect Basic White Rice", "Ingr": "Rice"],
            ["id":"Baba Ghanoush", "Ingr": "Eggplant, Onions ,Garlic, Lemon, Parsley"],
            ["id":"Really Fudgy Brownies", "Ingr": "Butter, Choclate, Vanilla, Flour"],
            ["id":"Simple Healthy Summer Salad", "Ingr": "Lettuce, Spinach, Cucumbera, Tomato, Olive Oil"],
            ["id":"Fried Mashed Potato", "Ingr": "Potato, Onion"],
            ["id":"Gnocci", "Ingr": "Potato, egg, Flavor"],
            ["id":"Piyaz", "Ingr": "Potato, egg, Flour"],
            ["id":"Rice Puding", "Ingr": "Rice, Milk,"],
           
        ]

        // there is an error at var newArray
var newArray = array.filter { $0["Ingr"] == "Rice" }//here only rice is checked.
        print(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the ingredients as a comma separated `String`, you should be storing them as an `Array<String>`.  For example, your entry for Gnocci, should be:

`["id":"Gnocci", "Ingr": ["Potato", "Egg", "Flavor"]]`

Then you could filter successfully.  Here's a full example

```
let array = [
    ["id":"Simple and healty salmon", "Ingr": ["Salmon", "Egg"]],
    ["id":"Boiled Eggs", "Ingr": ["Egg"]],
    ["id":"Perfect Basic White Rice", "Ingr": ["Rice"]]
]

let results = array.filter { recipe in
    if let ingredients = recipe["Ingr"] as? Array<String> {
        return ingredients.indexOf("Egg") != nil
    }
    return false
}
```

results will contains only the first two items in the original array